# Infinite series $e^x$ using interation

Tags: sequences-and-series

1. I am trying to derive $e^x$ using integration as below:
   $$e^t \geq 1,\ where \ 0\leq t\leq x$$
   Integrating both sides:
   $$\int_0^x e^t dt \geq \int_0^x dt$$
   $$e^x-e^0 \geq x$$
   Now $e^t\geq 1+t$

   Integrating both sides:
   $$\int_0^x e^t dt \geq \int_0^x \left(1+t\right) dt$$
   $$e^x-e^0 \geq x+\frac{x^2}{2}$$
   $$e^x \geq 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}$$
   Further integration will yield:
   $$e^x \geq 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+.......$$
   $e^x$ can now be written as below:
   $$e^x \geq  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} $$
   $$E\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} $$
2. Other part of the question is to consider $h\left(x\right)=e^{-x} \times E\left(x\right)$ and
   prove $h'\left(x\right)=0$ for all real values of $x$.  This can be proved by expanding
   $$h\left(x\right)=e^{-x} \times \left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4} 
   {24}+.......\right)$$ and then differentiating.
3. The last part of the question: hence show that $e^x = E\left(x\right)$ for all real values of $x$.  How can we prove this using the answer in Q2.

Comment: **Big Hint :** $h'(x)=0$ for all $x$ $\implies h(x)=h(0)$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Forom $Q2$ you get $(e^{-x} E(x) )'=0$ hence $$e^{-x} E(x) =C$$
but setting $x=0$ you'll get $C=1$ and $$e^{-x} E(x) =1.$$